# If $\mu$ is a vector measure and $\nu$ is a measure with $\left\|\mu\right\|\le\nu$ on a generating semiring, are we able to conclude $|\mu|\le\nu$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$ be a measurable space
- $E$ be a $\mathbb R$-Banach space
- $\mu$ be a $E$-valued measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$
- $\nu$ be a nonnegative real-valued measure on $(\Omega,\mathcal A)$
- $\mathcal E\subseteq2^\Omega$ be a semiring with $\Omega\in\mathcal E$ and $\sigma(\mathcal E)=\mathcal A$

Let $|\mu|$ denote the total variation of $\mu$, i.e. $$|\mu|(A)=\sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^k\left\|\mu(A_i)\right\|_E:k\in\mathbb N\text{ and }A_1,\ldots,A_k\in\mathcal A\text{ are pairwise disjoint with }\biguplus_{i=1}^kA_i\subseteq A\right\}$$ for all $A\in\mathcal A$.

> If $$\left\|\mu(A)\right\|_E\le\nu(A)\;\;\;\text{for all }A\in\mathcal E\tag1\;,$$ are we able to conclude $|\mu|\le\nu$?

My first problem is that even when $A\in\mathcal E$, the supremum in the definition of $|\mu|(A)$ is taken over partitions from all of $\mathcal A$ ... Maybe it's possible to show that in that case $$|\mu|(A)=\sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^k\left\|\mu(A_i)\right\|_E:k\in\mathbb N\text{ and }A_1,\ldots,A_k\in\mathcal E\text{ are pairwise disjoint with }\biguplus_{i=1}^kA_i\subseteq A\right\}\;.$$

Comment: The notation's off in (1), using $E$ for two different things(?) Also one of the $\nu$'s must be $\mu$(?)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry, fixed both.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer, a long comment:

First, the answer is not clear to me even if $\mu$ is a complex measure; there must be an answer to that out there somewhere.

A Banach-space valued measure can be nastier than I realized until just now. In particular, $|\mu|$ need not be a finite measure; this may make the vector-valued case harder.

Simple example where in fact $|\mu(A)|=\infty$ for every $A$ with $\nu(A)>0$: Let $\nu$ be Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$, and for $A\subset\Bbb R$ define $\mu(A)\in L^2(\Bbb R)$ by $$\mu(A)=\frac1{1+|t|}\chi_A(t).$$

Not that that's a counterexample, but if $|\mu|$ can be that bad it's hard to see how you're going to prove it has any sane properties.

**Oh**, speaking of counterexamples, no you can't  redefine $|\mu|$ in terms of sets in that semiring: Let $\mu=\nu=$ Lebesgue measure on $\Bbb R$, and consider the generating semiring consisting of finite unions of half-open intervals. If $A$ is compact and has positive measure and empty interior you're sunk.

Comment: You're right, the redefinition is not possible if $\mathcal E$ is a semiring, but did you notice that it is possible if $\mathcal E$ is an algebra? That assumption would be acceptable for me.

Comment: @0xbadf00d What??? Say $\mathcal E$ is the class of finite unions of $[a,b)$, and $(-\infty,b)$, where we allow $b=\infty$. So it's an algebra. And now it follows that any set with empty interior has measure zero.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your example. I guess you're thinking about the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$, but that measure is not finite and hence is not a possible choice for $\mu$ ($\overline{\mathbb R}$ is not a possible choice for $E$). However, let me provide an outline of the proof of the claim that I made: For simplicity, please consider the situation of [my other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2654451/if-%ce%bc-is-a-vector-measure-and-%ce%bd-is-a-measure-with-%ce%bc%e2%89%aa%ce%bd-prove-that-the-uniformly).

Comment: Now, assume $\mu$ (the $\mu$ from the other question) has bounded variation $|\mu|$ and choose $\nu:=|\mu|$. $\nu$ is $\sigma$-additive and $$\left\|\mu(A)\right\|_E\le\nu(A)\;\;\;\text{for all }A\in\mathcal A$$ and hence $$\mu\ll\nu.$$ Thus, $\mu$ has a unique $\sigma$-additive extension $\overline\mu:\sigma(\mathcal A)\to E$ with $$\overline\mu\ll\overline\nu.$$

Comment: Now, all we need to do is showing $$\left\|\overline\mu(A)\right\|_E\le\overline\nu(A)\;\;\;\text{for all }A\in\sigma(\mathcal A),$$ since then $$|\mu|(A)\le\overline\nu(A)\;\;\;\text{for all }A\in\sigma(\mathcal A)$$ and the other inequality is trivial. So, let $A\in\sigma(\mathcal A)$. Since $\mathcal A$ is dense in $\sigma(\mathcal A)$ wrt $d_{\overline\nu}$ (see the other question for the notation), there is a sequence $(A_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}\subseteq\mathcal A$ with $$d_{\overline\nu}(A,A_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0.$$

Comment: Since $\overline\mu\ll\overline\nu$, $\overline\mu$ is (uniformly) continuous with respect to $d_{\overline\nu}$ and hence $$\mu(A_n)=\overline\mu(A_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\overline\mu(A).$$ Clearly, $$\nu(A_n)=\overline\nu(A_n)\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}\overline\nu(A)$$ and as $$\left\|\mu(A_n)\right\|_E\le\nu(A_n)\;\;\;\text{for all }n\in\mathbb N,$$ we conclude $$\left\|\overline\mu(A)\right\|_E\le\overline\nu(A).$$

Comment: Regardless of the context, if you define $|\mu|$ in terms of sets from that algebra $\mathcal E$ you get $|\mu(E)|=0$ whenever $E$ has empty interior.

Comment: Could you please explain in more detail why you think that this is in contradiction to my last four comments?

Comment: I thought the goal was to show that $\pverline\mu\le\overline\nu$. Redefining $|\mu|$ makes that a little too easy. Why not just define $|\mu|=0$ and be done with it?

Comment: We don't literally "redefine" $|\mu|$, I showed above that $|\mu|(A)$, as given in the question, coincides with $\sup\left\{\sum_{i=1}^k\left\|\mu(A_i)\right\|_E:k\in\mathbb N\text{ and }A_1,\ldots,A_k\in\mathcal E\text{ are pairwise disjoint with }\biguplus_{i=1}^kA_i\subseteq A\right\}$ for all $A\in\mathcal E$, if $\mathcal E$ is an algebra on $\Omega$.